# Optimizing foreach statement

Tags: php, foreach

This is my code:

```
<?php foreach ($classes as $str) foreach ($str as $class): ?>
...
<?php endforeach ?>
```

`$str` has just one string value with a random string index.

Can the first statement be optimized to reduce it to just one foreach?

Comment: what is the structure of `$classes`?

Comment: Since your `$classes` array appears to be 2D, you'll probably need 2 loops. Really, we need to know what is _in_ the array, and what you plan to do _in the loop_.

Comment: Most importang this is what you want to do with this data.

Comment: also, and maybe i'm wrong, but it seems like you are confusing "optimize" with "do everything in the shortest amount of space possible"

Comment: Without forgetting that writing *readable*, *understandable* and possibly self-documenting code is at least as important as writing code that runs fast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could flatten your `classes` array, but it wouldn't give you any performance benefit because internally, the flattening of an array will iterate over the entire array anyway.

The short answer is: no - there's no way to optimize this without changing the way that the `$classes` array is constructed (if that's possible) - assuming you need access to all of the 2nd-level children of the `$classes` array.

**Edit**: If your `$str` sub-array only has one random child with a random array index, you could use `current($str)` - it might prove to be **SLIGHTLY** faster than a `foreach`

Comment: as if you extracted this piece of writing from my heart :)